# How do I solve the following exponential and logarithmic equations? I can leave it in terms of $\log/\ln$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following exponential and logarithmic equations? I can leave it in terms of $\log/\ln$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{3^{-x}}{12}&=7\\\newline
e^{5x}&=4\\ \newline
\log_3(x-3)+\log_3(4)&=\log_3(2x-1)-\log_3(6)\\ \newline
\log_3(x+15)-\log_3(x-1)&=2\\ \newline
\log x+\log(x-3)&=1\\ \newline
\log_2(x-1)+\log_2(3)&=\log_{16}(2x)
\end{aligned}$$

I understand the basics of logarithms, but applying it to these problems kind of made me stuck.

Comment: First, move the non-exponentials to one side. For example... 
$$\frac{3^{-x}}{12} = 7$$ 
$$3^{-x}=84$$ 
$$\ln(3^{-x})=\ln(84)$$ 
Use $\ln a^b = b\cdot\ln a$
$$-x\cdot\ln3=\ln84$$
$$x=-\frac{\ln84}{\ln3}$$
Use $\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}=\log_b a$
$$x=-\log_3 84$$

Just use log rules for the others, e.g. $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question so that we do not have to guess what you intended to write.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$\log x+\log(x-3)=1\iff\log(x(x-3))=
\log 10\iff x^2-3x-10=0\implies\ldots$$

Or

$$\log_3(x-3)+\log_34=\log_3(2x-1)-\log_36\iff\log_3(4(x-3))=\log_3\frac{2x-1}6\iff$$

$$4(x-3)=\frac{2x-1}6\implies\ldots$$

and etc.

Comment: Thank you! I kind of get the idea now! The ones I am really having an issue with are logx+log(x-3)=1, and the very last one.

Comment: @MNS213 One is already done above, and in the last one change basis on the right side $$\log_{16}(2x)=\frac{\log_2(2x)}{\log_216}$$

Comment: Sorry for the commenting again, but how would I leave the answer for the two questions you showed above in ln or log form?

Comment: @MNS213 I don't understand your comment: in both cases you have to solve a simple equation for $\;x\;$, without exponentials or logarithms...!

Comment: For the first example you provided, would the answer to x be 2?

Comment: Well, no. Observe that $\;x^2-3x-10=(x-5)(x+2)=0\implies x=-2\;$ or $\;x=5\;$ . But $\;x=-2\;$ **cannot be** since substituting in the original equation would render $\;log(-2)\;$, and this is undefined in the real numbers. Thus, the *only solution* is $\;x=5\;$ ...I think you should go over your notes on the very definition of logarithms, basic properties, etc.